# htaccess - how to only allow access to subfolders within its redirect/directoryindex?

Tags: .htaccess

Bit of a confusing one.

My website structure in GoDaddy is as follows:

```
/public_html
 /folder1/
  /index.html
  /folder2/
   /index.html
 /restrictedfolder
 /secretfolder
```

I've created a .htaccess file inside the 'public_html' root which contains the following:

```
DirectoryIndex /folder1/index.html http://example.com
```

If I go to mysite.com, it directs me to the folder1 and shows my home page correctly. My URL (to the user) remains as mysite.com which is what I want. The problems I have are:
 - If I go to example.com/folder1 (this still shows my index.html)
 - If I go to example.com/restrictedfolder (this still shows my index.html)
 - If I go to example.com/secretfolder (this still shows my index.html)

I do want example.com/folder2 to work though.

Answer (score 1):

From this https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_dir.html

> The DirectoryIndex directive sets the list of resources to look for,
>   when the client requests an index of the directory by specifying a /
>   at the end of the directory name. Local-url is the (%-encoded) URL of
>   a document on the server relative to the requested directory; it is
>   usually the name of a file in the directory. Several URLs may be
>   given, in which case the server will return the first one that it
>   finds. If none of the resources exist and the Indexes option is set,
>   the server will generate its own listing of the directory.

In short , if you put:

```
DirectoryIndex index.html
```

that means Whenever request targeting a directory index like this `example.com/directory/` as well as `example.com` a server will look to `index.html` file , otherwise directory listing will happen unless you prevent that by other options .

In your case , the request for your website will go to  `/folder1/index.html` normally but when the request is going to a directory server will get this again because you add `/` in front of target path so whenever request to index of directory will be only for `/folder1/index.html`.

If you change it to `DirectoryIndex folder1/index.html` you will notice that,when request is going to directory index, a directory listing will happen even there is an index page ,because a server will look to `folder1/index.html` inside that directory.

And if you just make a try and add the same folder name `folder1/index.html` at any directory with different content in index.html for example `restrictedfolder`  so there will be true path `/restrictedfolder/folder1/index.html` when you request `example.com/restrictedfolder/` like this you will see the content of index.html inside `restrictedfolder/folder1/`.

To solve this issue you could use `mod_rewrite` to make `folder1` as website root without changing a URI.

**Moreover**, don't put the host name like this

`DirectoryIndex /folder1/index.html http://example.com`

This directive only accept local-uri .

Also you could do something like this if you want to add another page :

```
DirectoryIndex   index.html index.php
```

So , if there is no `index.html` in that directory server will look to `index.php` and so on .